# When to use selector and when to use blocking channels (performence)

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, selector, channel

- Assume that there are 1 to 30~ channels (UDP & TCP channels)
- Assume that we use NIO channels
- Assume we are running on Multi core CPU
  There are 2 options:

  1. Define 1 thread per channel (each thread will be blocked till there is data to read)
     (so all the thread are in the waiting Q ... till they wake up)
     or:
  2. Define 1 thread (with selector) which will read the data (each time from different channel)
- what is the best way ?
- what will give me the best performance ?

Comment: The answer really depends on your requirements.  Do you need the lowest latencies or the highest throughput? How many cores can you dedicate to this?

Comment: I'm write an asset. so the latencies , throughput and #cores can be changed ...

Answer (score 0):

In Java you don't have much control over the thread (concrete) mechanisms so you can't really bind a thread to a certain core (setting the affinity for example) so you cannot expect much performance difference from having a single thread processing via a selector or having multiple per-channel threads.

Given the introduction that I just gave, let's talk on a higher level, ok?

When you have multiple threads, one per channel, and considering a multiple-core processor there is the possibility of having N threads (where N is the number of cores) executing at the same time, if you have a single thread processing a queue of requests it could have some speed if we could guarantee that once a certain request is made there isn't another request arriving. Either way the processing of the threads will end up going through context-switch wich takes the thread out of the core, see if there is something else that has to be done, and if not, put some thread back on the core to execute.

What happens sometimes is that you thread keeps moving from one core to another and this kills the cache which ends up decreasing performance (as many other factos also affect).

So, depending on how much requests will arriving at the same time I would prefer the multiple threads approach.

Cheers.

Comment: BTW To bind a thread to a core in Java try https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity

Comment: @PeterLawrey it seems interesting! However I based my answer on the core libs provided with Java. I will take a look on this project, thanks for the reference.

Comment: Thanks, 
so, according to what you wrote here, when we use selectors ? what is the benefit to use selector and not a multiple threads (thread per channel...) ?

Comment: My understanding is that selectors will allow you to use less resources by using only one thread. The use will depend on the problem, but as I said, for maximum throughput mulriple threads will allow you to have multiple tasks being performed at the same time.